# Is there a phase diagram for $\rm CO_2$ below 1 millibar?

Tags: pressure, phase-transition, phase-diagram

Considering $\rm CO_2$ snow on Mars and recent cold temperature on the earths' south pole, I am looking for a $\rm CO_2$ phase diagram below 1 millibar that shows the sublimation temperature of $\rm CO_2$ for $\rm CO_2$ partial pressure in earths atmosphere, (i.e. 0.4 millibar).

Comment: Duplicate? [Is there a temperature-pressure phase diagram of carbon dioxide for the lowest temperatures and pressures?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/430227/)

Comment: The lowest I found was 0.001 atm. That is why I asked. researchgate reference even stops at 0.01 atm.

Comment: @Farcher - indeed, the J. Phys. Chem. Ref. reference in one of the answers has the answer. A complicated answer, but the answer nonetheless.

Comment: Jon that reference is behind a paywal: so in theory, yes, a good answer, however,  in practise it isn't if you just need a phase diagram and you are not affiliated to an institute with a journal subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this formula from Giauque & Egan (1937) for the sublimation part of the Phase diagram: p in atm, T in Kelvin.
p=0.0131579 * 10^(-(1354.210/T)+8.69903+0.001588*T-(4.5107*10^-6)*T^2)

Plotted here from -170 to -56 deg °C and 1ppm to 10 bar CO2
[image: CO2 phase diagram between 1 ppm and 10 bar and -170 °C and -56 °C]

Source:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Carbon_Dioxide_sublimation_curve.png Using Giauque, W.F.; Egan, C.J., Carbon Dioxide. The Heat Capacity and Vapor Pressure of the Solid. The Heat of Sublimation. Thermodynamic and Spectroscopic Values of the Entropy, J. Chem. Phys., 1937, 5, 1, 45-54, https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1749929 (strictly only valid from 154.26K to 195.89K)

Units:
Original Giauque-Egan pressure is in centimeter of mercury, conversion to kPa is 1.333224, divide by 101.325 to get atm, rounded to six significant places according to [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/pml/special-publication-811/nist-guide-si-appendix-b-conversion-factors/nist-guide-si-appendix-b8): 0.0131579, temperature is in Kelvin: convert to degrees Celsius using °C = T -273.15

Alternative formula ([NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C124389&Mask=4&Type=ANTOINE&Plot=on)):
p = 10^ (6.81228 − (1301.67 / (T -3.494))) (p in bar, T in Kelvin)